# Angular JS UI Grid Row merging

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have done cell merge in this plunker given below 
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c65CZm19bGJbWfZT15u6?p=preview)

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    rowHeight:50,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'phoneList', name: 'Phone Numbers', cellTemplate:'<div ng-repeat="item in row.entity[col.field]">{{item}}</div>'}
    ],
     enableColumnResizing: true
  };

  $http.get('data.json')
  .success(function (data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
  });
}]);
```

]

but i want the division of rows in phone number. 
the name should be one row divided into 2 rows having phone number. 
Where as now i am having multiple phone numbers in single row. 
Can anyone please help me with this issue . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it exactly what you want?

Comment: I want one row to be divided into two rows

Comment: So that name is one row and all phonenumbers are separate rows below the name row? And should they have the "title" still above them?